# Sequelize, lazy loading on associated models

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am using sequelize 6.17

I have a class Folders which has many childFolders and files.

I would like to lazy load the childFolders and files that are on the association.

```
const folderContent = await db.folders.findAll({
            where: {
               parentFolderId: 123
            },
            limit,
            offset,
            include: [
               {
                  model: db.folders,
                  as: "childFolders",
                  required: false
               },
               {
                  model: db.files,
                  as: "files",
                  required: false
               }
            ],
         });
```

This will not work and will return `folderContent.files` and `folderContent.childFolders`.

Would be possible to get x amount of childFolders and when there is not anymore childFolders to start getting the files? Can this be returned as an array of childFolders and files?

Answer (score 2):

By indicating `include` option you perform `eager` loading and you will get all-in-one. If you wish to get `childFolders` or `files` separately for a certain `folder` model instance you need to call special methods `getChildFolders` or `getFiles` (generated by Sequelize):

```js
const folderContent = await db.folders.findAll({
            where: {
               parentFolderId: 123
            },
            limit,
            offset,
         });

for (const folder of folders) {
  const files = await folder.getFiles();
  const childFolders = await folder.getChildFolders();
}
```

Comment: See more here: [Fetching associations - Eager Loading vs Lazy Loading](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#fetching-associations---eager-loading-vs-lazy-loading)